# ASP.NET MVC & Silverlight

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

Should an ASP.NET MVC Developer start to learn Silverlight either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is a server side framework, Silverlight runs on the client. While they can work together in a single application, they are meant to do very different things. It's not necessary to know Silverlight to use ASP.NET MVC.

If you need to create mixed applications with Silverlight on the client and ASP.NET MVC on the server, you'll need to know Silverlight.